# AngularJS template not loading locally, but will load in Plnkr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localhost

I'm trying to get a proof of concept going locally with this plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/at8SXmvb2LkWYtuZE9Vm?p=preview

Everything works fine in plnkr, but when I download the zip, and run a simple Node server, the templates won't load up at http://localhost:8080. All I get is the tab title, but not the content inside of the template. There are no errors in the console either, so I'm wondering what's wrong?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Here's what the controller looks like:

```
.controller('TabsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.tabs = [{
      title: 'One',
      url: 'one.html'
    }, {
      title: 'Two',
      url: 'two.html'
    }, {
      title: 'Three',
      url: 'three.html'
    }];

    $scope.currentTab = 'one.html';

    $scope.onClickTab = function(tab) {
      $scope.currentTab = tab.url;
    }

    $scope.isActiveTab = function(tabUrl) {
      return tabUrl == $scope.currentTab;
    }
  }]);
```

Comment: How can we help you if you dont have errors and it doesn't work :). Suppose you have some conflicts. Open chrome developer view and check 'Sources' tab. In left side be sure you loaded all stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I wasn't putting my HTML templates in the proper format. Instead of just adding `<h1>Hello World</h1>,` I needed to also include the `<html>` and `<body>` tags.